# Get specific attribute from array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to get all Ids of the company Users and add it to the int array:

```
  userListIds: state.ddls.companyUsers.forEach(function (element) {
    ---How to add it to the int array
  });
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does the same from @aseferov but its written in ES6:

```
userListIds: state.ddls.companyUsers.map(element => element.id);
```

Answer (score 2):

use map

```
 userListIds: state.ddls.companyUsers.map(function (element) {
     return element.id
  });
```